# clicking on the notification do not open new activity when its target activity is open

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I have two activity MainActivity and ReceivedMessageActivity. and a background service for get Context from it and pass to SMSReceiver that extends BroadcastReceiver for receiving sms. and when an sms received  SMSReceiver creates notification. I want when I clicked on notification if the app is not running the ReceivedMessageActivity be opened and when the app is running and if the ReceivedMessageActivity is open don't create new Activity by intent and just brought to front the ReceivedMessageActivity. I set the launchMode in manifest to singleTop , for MainActivity is working but for ReceivedMessageActivity not work ! I set notification intent flag to FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP but dos not work. i set manifest launchMode for ReceivedMessageActivity to singleInstance its work but when i lunch the ReceivedMessageActivity manually the default animation of it not working ( right to left animation ). this is my code for notification :

```
public void addNotifiction(String title, String message) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new     
    NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setStyle(new 
    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.edit_icon);
    builder.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

    Intent notifactionIntent = new Intent(context,     
    ReceivedMessagesActivity.class);
    notifactionIntent 
  .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(notifictionIntent);
    PendingIntent contentPendingIntent= taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent (0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, builder.build());
```

}

and my context is MyService class context :

```
Context context=MyService.context
```

**EDIT** : I found that when I use `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"`
in manifest for receivedMessageActivity this happen and when i click in notification and receivedMessageActivity is open my app create new receivedMessageActivity why ?

Comment: try to use `implcit intent` with pending intent when app is in background !

Comment: how to us imlcit intent ?

Comment: intent initilialized with `intent-filter` given to an activity P.S idk what `TaskStackBuilder` is

Answer (score 0):

Basic Skeleton of Notification maker from one of my apps hope it help:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
String title = context.getString(R.string.title);
String subtitle = context.getString(R.string.subtitle);

Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = null;
//        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ReceivedMessageActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
            context,
            CHANNEL_ID)
    ) //
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(subtitle)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            getBaseContext(),
                            0,
                            intent,
                            0
                    )
            )
            .setAutoCancel(true);

} else {
    notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context) //
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(subtitle)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            getBaseContext(),
                            0,
                            intent,
                            0
                    )
            )
            .setAutoCancel(true);
}
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());// only in case you are in service
```

Following code is not tested

Comment: it is not my answer i want to if an activity is open when i click on notification dont create new same activity

Comment: this code do the same task required , i am already using this code

Comment: read my edited post . do you have an idea about that ?
and what is startForeground ? startForeground not work for me